# Magento 2 : How To Add Cms Block on Home Page After Megamenu

Tags: magento2, layout, cms-block, cms-pages, page

I need to create a link from cms block to the home page to render the contents in storefront.

Comment: have you tried @Price Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**You have two ways to do that**

1. **Using xml**

**`app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml`**

```
    <referenceContainer name="header">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Blockname" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id_here" xsi:type="string">blockname</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

2. **Insert the below code in header in your current theme path:**

**`app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Cms/templates/html/header.phtml`**

```
    <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_id_here')->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Admin Side:**

**Step 1: Create a CMS Block**

1. Log in to your Magento 2 Admin Panel.
2. Go to Content > Elements > Blocks.
3. Click on the "Add New Block" button.
4. Enter a Block Title (e.g., "Home Page Block") and Identifier (e.g.,
   "home-page-block").
5. In the Content field, add the content for your block.
6. Click on the "Save" button.

**Step 2: Assign the CMS Block to the Home Page**

1. Go to Content > Elements > Pages.
2. Find and edit the home page.
3. In the Content section, locate the area where you want to display
   the CMS block after the mega menu.
4. Insert the following code at the desired position:

**`{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="home-page-block"}}`**

Replace "home-page-block" with the identifier of the CMS block you created in Step 1.

5. Save the changes.

Step 3: Clear Cache

After making changes to the CMS blocks and pages, it's a good practice to clear the cache to ensure the changes take effect. You can do this by going to System > Cache Management and clicking on the "Flush Magento Cache" button.

Now, when you visit your home page, the CMS block will be displayed after the mega menu. Make sure to adjust the CSS and layout as needed to achieve the desired positioning and styling.